unable to get cheese to work
I wonder if someone knows how to track down this problem on Ubuntu 22.04. Webcam is Logitech c270 HD. My rights in group videos is drwxr-xr-x I had quite a few problems with cheese version 41. But most of the prblems are gone with version 44. I can see myself in webcam and even take apicture, but when i try to record a video I get blackscreen with "There was an error playing video from webcam"
snap run cheese
Gtk-Message: 12:04:26.174: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.

(cheese:11433): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:04:26.240: GTK+ module /snap/cheese/40/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 12:04:26.240: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(cheese:11433): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:04:26.242: GTK+ module /snap/cheese/40/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 12:04:26.242: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(cheese:11433): cheese-WARNING **: 12:04:27.268: Can't find vp8enc preset: "Profile Realtime", using alternate preset: "Cheese Realtime". If you see this, make a bug report!

(cheese:11433): GStreamer-WARNING **: 12:04:27.268: gst_value_deserialize_g_value_array: unimplemented

(cheese:11433): GStreamer-WARNING **: 12:04:27.268: gst_value_deserialize_g_value_array: unimplemented

(cheese:11433): GStreamer-WARNING **: 12:04:27.268: gst_value_deserialize_g_value_array: unimplemented

(cheese:11433): GStreamer-WARNING **: 12:04:27.274: gst_value_deserialize_g_value_array: unimplemented

(cheese:11433): GStreamer-WARNING **: 12:04:27.274: gst_value_deserialize_g_value_array: unimplemented

(cheese:11433): GStreamer-WARNING **: 12:04:27.274: gst_value_deserialize_g_value_array: unimplemented

(cheese:11433): cheese-WARNING **: 12:04:34.769: Failed to connect stream: Access denied: ../ext/pulse/pulsesrc.c(1622): gst_pulsesrc_prepare (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstAutoAudioSrc:audiosrc/GstPulseSrc:audiosrc-actual-src-puls


(cheese:11433): cheese-WARNING **: 12:04:34.770: Internal data stream error.: ../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstAutoAudioSrc:audiosrc/GstPulseSrc:audiosrc-actual-src-puls:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)


Did you try changing the resolution? See here.

Changing resolution has no effect on my problem.

After installation of Ubuntu 24.04 seems my problem is gone.
